# VS 2012 ArgumentNullException in designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have recently upgraded to VS 2012 after creating my WPF project in VS 2010, now I receive the following error in design mode:

[image: Exception]

This error does not stop me from compiling and debugging my project but I cannot view the design of my controls!

I'm thinking this might be a problem with the actual VS 2012 designer.

Any ideas?

-- UPDATE

Here is my constructor for one of the controls with the problem:

```
public DepositLinkCtl()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Loaded += DepositLinkCtl_Loaded;
}
```

Comment: Do you installed the Update 1 for Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Yes I have installed the update.

Comment: Do you have starting something in the default constructor?

Comment: View my updated question for the constructor.